# Apply natural sort for email Id's which uses ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an email list which is exporting from excel sheet and i want to display them sorting by using natural sort in the output.

Can any one help me in this regard. 
I want to know what wrong I am doing here. and how to correct it. A working solution would be greatly appreciated.

Basically the output should be sorted emails

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["naturalSort"]).

controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) { 
    $scope.items = ["xxx1@gmail.com","xxx13@gmail.com","xxx12@gmail.com","number 3.com","xxx21@gmail.com" , "number 4@gmail.com", "xxx11@gmail.com" , "xxx13@gmail.com"
    ]
}]);

// Create a module for naturalSorting
angular.module("naturalSort", [])

// The core natural service
.factory("naturalService", ["$locale", function($locale) {
  // the cache prevents re-creating the values every time, at the expense of
  // storing the results forever. Not recommended for highly changing data
  // on long-term applications.
 var natCache = {},
  // amount of extra zeros to padd for sorting
        padding = function(value) {
   return '00000000000000000000'.slice(value.length);
  },
  
  // Calculate the default out-of-order date format (d/m/yyyy vs m/d/yyyy)
        natDateMonthFirst = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.shortDate.charAt(0) == 'm';
  // Replaces all suspected dates with a standardized yyyy-m-d, which is fixed below
        fixDates = function(value) {
   // first look for dd?-dd?-dddd, where "-" can be one of "-", "/", or "."
            return value.replace(/(\d\d?)[-\/\.](\d\d?)[-\/\.](\d{4})/, function($0, $m, $d, $y) {
    // temporary holder for swapping below
                var t = $d;
    // if the month is not first, we'll swap month and day...
                if(!natDateMonthFirst) {
                    // ...but only if the day value is under 13.
                    if(Number($d) < 13) {
                        $d = $m;
                        $m = t;
                    }
                } else if(Number($m) > 12) {
     // Otherwise, we might still swap the values if the month value is currently over 12.
                    $d = $m;
                    $m = t;
                }
    // return a standardized format.
                return $y+'-'+$m+'-'+$d;
            });
        },
  
  // Fix numbers to be correctly padded
        fixNumbers = function(value) {
    // First, look for anything in the form of d.d or d.d.d...
            return value.replace(/(\d+)((\.\d+)+)?/g, function ($0, integer, decimal, $3) {
    // If there's more than 2 sets of numbers...
                if (decimal !== $3) {
                    // treat as a series of integers, like versioning,
                    // rather than a decimal
                    return $0.replace(/(\d+)/g, function ($d) {
                        return padding($d) + $d
                    });
                } else {
     // add a decimal if necessary to ensure decimal sorting
                    decimal = decimal || ".0";
                    return padding(integer) + integer + decimal + padding(decimal);
                }
            });
        },

  // Finally, this function puts it all together.
        natValue = function (value) {
            if(natCache[value]) {
                return natCache[value];
            }
            var newValue = fixNumbers(fixDates(value));
            return natCache[value] = newValue;
        };

 // The actual object used by this service
 return {
  naturalValue: natValue,
  naturalSort: function(a, b) {
   a = natVale(a);
   b = natValue(b);
   return (a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0)
  }
 };
}])

// Attach a function to the rootScope so it can be accessed by "orderBy"
.run(["$rootScope", "naturalService", function($rootScope, naturalService) {
 $rootScope.natural = function (field) {
        return function (item) {
            return naturalService.naturalValue(item[field]);
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:natural('item')">            
              {{ item }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can any one please help me here. I am really stuck with this for 2 days. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Aron, the solution is unnecessarily complex.

But, the actual issue is in the line

```
return naturalService.naturalValue(item[field]);
```

Here, item refers to the email, so item[field] is always going to be undefined. This undefined gets passed to the sort method and causes an exception. Replace the above line with:

```
return naturalService.naturalValue(item);
```

And your sort seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like major overkill. Have you tried getting rid of everything in the `naturalSort` module and simply having an `orderBy` with no arguments? I.e.:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy">{{item}}</li>
```

Check out this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/a9djLBSav7gv1WZgv2oB?p=preview).

Sorting strings alphabetically is part of the `OrderBy` directive's default behaviour.

Comment: is natural sorting not supported with angular 1.4.8 version? I am getting injector  modulerr error when trying to load other things. When i remove 'naturalSort' from the app.module() other modules  seems to be working. What should i do?

Comment: What modules are you trying to load? `naturalSort` is not a native Angular module.

Comment: i am trying to load kind of all sort (from date time picker, custom directives, cookies, bootstrap and lots of other stuff...  ngRoute, Image uploading etc

Comment: To do that you need to load other scripts from your html and then inject them as dependencies in the module declaration, like you've tried to do with `['naturalSort']`